# How to smooth the water mesh in a water simulation?

Tags: mesh, smooth

i am making a water simulation but after baking , the water mesh has flat triangles as shown in the picture below , i tried subdivision surface but it gets the performance way too bad ,and also tried shade smooth on the mesh , any smart way to smooth the mesh without heavy performance issues ? Thanks in advance

[image: Picture]

Comment: Turning on Shade Smooth is usually the way to go. What was the problem with that? The subdivision surface modifier adds more geometry which leads to decrease in performance. But the shade smooth is just a trick. So it not compute heavy or anything.

Comment: Yes you need to shade smooth and add a Subdivision Surface modifier, if it's not enough you need to tweak your fluid parameters but of course it will take more time to calculate

Comment: @TheKalaakaar yeah the shade smooth is already applied in the picture abovee , but when i zoom in a bit as you can see there are still flat surfaces in there , and the final render ( with materials ) look a bit unrealistic

Comment: @moonboots i shaded smooth the mesh , but the sub-surface is a let go in this case cause it makes blender completely unusable ! i baked at  a resolution of 140 , i guess i will experiment with other parameters or trick it in the shading stage !

Comment: From what I remember you need to increase the Resolution Divisions value?

Comment: Yes i increased it to 140 , so it wont take hours to bake

Comment: Does it improve the result?

Comment: The preview above is already at 140 subdivisions in the simulation , but smooth shading and tweaking other parameters i think will improve the mesh i think ! I'm still experimenting because i have a glass cylinder that i want to fill with a liquid loop and im still changing things here and there

Comment: The final simulation render i will definitely make smthg like 200 subdivisions for sure , but after i get the only the cylinder filled with water ( i have other objects and meshes in the scene )